# Free Shipping Calculation Problem, Possible Fraud Order, Exploit or Misconfiguration?

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, security, free-shipping

We have a rule setup to give free shipping on orders over $49.  We had a very suspicious order come through where the discount didn't make sense:

[image]

You can see in the screenshot the only coupon listed in savings is the "eligible for free shipping".  Yet they got $150 listed here.  If you look at the product rows they got a hefty discount for each item in the order.

This person paid with the standard magento paypal module.

Here's our Shopping Cart Price Rule config:

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So it it a misconfig or exploit?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks right (i.e. it should only result in free shipping)

I cannot find anything related in the [Magento 1 bug tracker](https://magento.com/tech-resources/bug-tracking), also not in the [Magento 1.9.x release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html), so it does not look like a known issue or exploit.

This does not mean that there cannot be an unknown exploit, but I find it more likely that it's not a core issue, but a bug in an extension. So review your sales related extensions and make sure they are up to date.

If you can reproduce the order, try disabling extensions one by one until you found the one that causes this behavior.